# CSS, float:left adds hidden padding?

Tags: css

I'm very new to the html5/css universe.
I'm trying to do something very basic and cannot comprehend why I'm getting the results I am. I would like to add a sidebar to the side of my content. I'm doing this by adding a 310px margin to my content and putting floating my side-content there. Easy!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
  div.sidebar{float:left;width:300px;padding:0;background-color:yellow;}
  div.content{margin-left:310px;background-color:green;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="sidebar">
<h1>Sidebar</h1>
</div>

<div class="content">
<h1>Content</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But something odd is happening, there seems to be a 1em padding above and below the sidebar (yellow), but not the content (green). As a consequence the titles "Sidebar" and "Content" are not aligned. I'm just wondering why the float:left automatically added what seems to be padding? And can this padding be removed? padding:0; seems to have no effect.

Comment: This will be due to the `margin` applied to `h1` elements.  Because `.content` is not floated the margins are collapsing. Remove the `margin` from `h1` and the issue will disappear. There are other options which will probably be suggested by someone else in a proper answer.

Comment: Although I accepted the answer below, this is explanation is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: No problem @Chris, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <style>
      body,html{margin:0;padding:0px}
      div.sidebar{display:inline-block;float:left;width:300px;padding:0;background-color:yellow;}
      div.content{margin-left:10px;display:inline-block;float:left;background-color:green;}
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="sidebar">
    <h1>Sidebar</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
    <h1>Content</h1>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Aha! I tried to `float:left` the `.content`, but that made things worse. Also adding a `display:inline-block` does the trick!

Comment: Good, happy Coding

Answer (score -1):

Every browser has its own default ‘user agent’ stylesheet, that it uses to make elements appear more legible. For example, most browsers by default make links blue and visited links purple, give tables a certain amount of border and padding, apply variable font-sizes to H1, H2, H3 etc. and a certain amount of padding to almost everything. The padding your are having is because of default browser setting. Try a global reset for elements.

eg: * {margin:0;padding:0}